# Set Row number based on Cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to select a range based on the value of a cell from another worksheet and then printout the given range but it breaks when trying to use my value as the row number. I have tried changing the syntax and trying different methods to get it to accept but I cannot find an answer.

```
Sub Print_Other()

Dim rng As Integer
Dim a   As Variant                                     
    a = Sheets("SAP").Range("J3").Value
    rng = Sheets("Selector").Range("R19").Row          'the value of this cell is 50

With Worksheets("Selection to Print")
    .Range("1:125").EntireRow.Hidden = True            'hide all rows
    .Range.Row("1 :" & rng).EntireRow.Hidden = False   'un-hide the rows for printing 'breaks here
    .PrintOut from:=1, to:=a                           'printout the given pages 
    .Range("1:125").EntireRow.Hidden = False           'un-hide all
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: `.Range("1:" & rng).EntireRow.Hidden = False `

Comment: `Dim rng As Integer` - try something clearer and less misleading than `rng`, which typically stands for `Range`.

Comment: `rng = Sheets("Selector").Range("R19").Value`

Comment: Also I do not see where you are assigning a value to `a`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the updated code, thanks to the comments from Scott Craner & BigBen:

```
Sub Print_Other()

    Dim a As Variant
    Dim b As Variant
    Dim c As Variant
    Dim d As Integer

    a = Sheets("SAP").Range("J3").Value
    b = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(Int(a / 5), 0)
    c = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(Int(a / 10), 0)
    d = Sheets("Compound Breakdown").Range("R19").Value
    
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With Worksheets("Hot Mixer Hand Adds")
    .Range("1:125").EntireRow.Hidden = True      
    .Range("1:" & d).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    .PrintOut from:=1, to:=b
    .Range("1:125").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End With

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```